# GET http://localhost:4200/profile/1 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, api, get

profile.service.ts

```
  getProfile(userId:number): Observable<UserModel> {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserModel>('/profile/inquireUserInfo/' + userId);
  }
```

profile.component.ts

```
  private getProfile() {
    this.profileService.getProfile(this.userId).subscribe(data => {
      this.userModel = data;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

However, when I run this application, I get a 404 error as seen in the image below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the value of this.userId which is passed into the service class. The URL shows undefined at the end of it.

Comment: `getProfile(userId:number): Observable<UserModel> {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserModel>('/profile/inquireUserInfo/1');
  }`   so it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not sending `api/profile/...` with your service, as your proxy reversing `api` routes to backend server.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the problem. Try this url instead: `'/api/profile/inquireUserInfo/' + userId`

Comment: Thank you for help me. Worked. `@GetMapping(path = "/api/profile/{userId}"`

Comment: Simple but common issue. :) Take it easy.